# Vector Iterator within an iterator error

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, 2d-games

Working on an asteroid game for my portfolio. Game across an error with the following block of code. The error is simply that the iterator is not deferencable, but I've narrowed the error down. I'll talk about that after I've shown you the code:

```
void Game::Update()
{
if (elapsedTime > REFRESH_RATE)
{
    player->Update(elapsedTime);

    std::vector<Asteroid*>::iterator iterator= bigAsteroids.begin();
    std::vector<Bullet*>::iterator iter = bullets.begin();

    // *********************** //
    while (iterator!= bigAsteroids.end())
    {
        if (*iterator != nullptr) // Checks to see if player is colliding with an asteroid and updates the asteroid
        {
            player->CheckCollisionsAsteroid( *iterator );

            // *********************** // Checks to see if bullet is colliding with asteroid 
            while (iter != bullets.end())
            {
                if (*iter != nullptr)
                {
                    if ((*iter)->CheckCollisionsAsteroid( **iterator ))
                    {
                        size_t i = iterator - bigAsteroids.begin();
                        iter = bullets.erase(iter);
                        iterator = bigAsteroids.erase(iterator);
                        printf("\nAsteroid destroyed at position %i", i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++iter;
                    }
                }
            }
            iter = bullets.begin(); // Reset the bullet iterator else we'd only get to check 1 asteroid

            // *********************** //
            if (*iterator != nullptr && iterator != bigAsteroids.end()) { (*iterator)->Update(elapsedTime); }
        }
        if (*iterator != nullptr && (iterator!= bigAsteroids.end()))
        {++iterator;}
    }
    // *********************** //
    Clock.Reset(); 
}
}
```

If it all looks a bit messy, here's a brief explanation:

As the iterator passes through each of the asteroids, I check if the player is colliding with each of the asteroids. *At present this does nothing*

I then iterate through my vector of bullets, checking each bullet against the current asteroid. if there is a collision, I destroy erase both the bullet AND the asteroid, and print out what position the destroyed asteroid held in the vector.

Once I'm done with that, I reset the bullet iter for the next asteroid.

My major issue at present is the call to Update by the (*iterator) <-- asteroid.

The issue only crops up when I'm erasing the last object in the asteroids vector. I know erase returns an iterator to the next object - if the next object doesn't exist, an error will be thrown (as the iterator is then pointing to a nullptr, correct?). I'm making the checks for a nullptr to no avail..

Does anyone have any advice or help they can offer? Would be much appreciated, been scratching my head for a good few hours!

Comment: It would help code readability significantly if you named your iterators after what they refer to, e.g. `itAsteroid` and `itBullet`.

Comment: @Angew I get this a lot haha, I keep rewriting code so at present so typing out bulletIter or asteroidIter over 'iter' or 'iterator'.. :P Final version will have those implemented, thanks. 

And BoB Hmmm.. I'll get back to you, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you destroy the last asteroid, `iterator` will be set to `bigAsteroids.end()` (by being assigned to the result of `erase()`). Then after the inner `while` loop terminates, you dereference `iterator`. The past-the-end iterator cannot be dereferenced.

You'll have to switch the order of checks:

```
if (iterator != bigAsteroids.end() && *iterator != nullptr)
```

Comment: It's not so much the last asteroid. It could be the first asteroid I shoot. If it's the LAST asteroid in the vector (as in the one at the end), then the error throws. I don't think I've managed to get down to one asteroid to shoot at present! Haha

Comment: He means: when you call `bigAsteroids.erase(iterator)`, `iterator` is set to `bigAsteroids.end()`. `*iterator != nullptr` will fail and `iterator != bigAsteroids.end()` will return `false`, so switch the order of conditions, and you should be fine

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. I see.

I did change it around:

`if (itAsteroid != bigAsteroids.end()) { (*itAsteroid)->Update(elapsedTime); }`

And this still caused errors. 

BUT, I then changed the line below:

   `if ( itAsteroid!= bigAsteroids.end() && *itAsteroid != nullptr ) {++itAsteroid;}`

And it did as you said. What'd I do with you guys :P Thanks both of you!